# Any online API/Web-Service to identify a word's nature and check grammar of sentence

Tags: nlp

We are discussing a project where we need to identify if a word is a noun, verb, pronoun etc. At the same time, we need to check a sentence if that is correct (grammatically).

This is a huge task to do from scratch, so I am wondering if there is any service/api available for this?

The application will be android based either native or phonegap based, so api compatible with the major languages will help immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LanguageTool [has an HTTPS API](http://wiki.languagetool.org/public-http-api) (disclosure: I'm the LanguageTool maintainer) for text checking. The part-of-speech information is available via its Java API, not via HTTP.