# Can Google Translate API tell if word is a noun or verb

Tags: google-translate

Can the Google Translate API tell me if a word is a noun or a verb?

The Google Translate site does, but I cant figure out if the Google Translate API does.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to use the [Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/reference/rest/v1beta1/documents/annotateText) instead.

Comment: hhmmm. i guess so. thanks very much!

Comment: But apparently it cannot handle Arabic? aarrgghh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any online API/Web-Service to identify a word's nature and check grammar of sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517601/any-online-api-web-service-to-identify-a-words-nature-and-check-grammar-of-sent)